# Is there any symbol (similar to Δ) for "relative difference"?

Tags: notation

The symbol for the absolute difference is $\Delta$.

$$
\Delta P = P_2 - P_1
$$

Is there an equivalent symbol for the relative difference?

$$
\text{Relative difference} = \frac{\Delta P}{P_1}
$$

Comment: Why not $\frac{\Delta P}{P}$?

Comment: $\delta P$ can do the trick, provided you define it explicitly.

Comment: That would be what I'm looking for. Do you have any example where $\delta P$ is used?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just $\frac{\Delta P}{P}$? For example, the relative uncertainty in $P = A \cdot B$ can be written as:

$$\frac{\Delta P}{P} = \frac{\Delta A}{A} + \frac{\Delta B}{B}$$

Comment: It has to be inline in a non-math oriented journal.

Comment: In that case, you can get away with writing $(\Delta P)/P$.

Comment: There is no $P$ ! There are $P_1,P_2, \Delta P$, but no $P$  in the OP's question (unlike $P\pm\Delta P$).